# I cant run an update query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function updateVisitsStatus($today){
        /*
         * 
        $this->db->select('exp_datetime, status_id');
        $this->db->from('visits');
        $this->db->where('exp_datetime <', $today);
        $this->db->where('status_id', 0);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->db->get()->result());exit;
         * 
         */

        $this->db->where('exp_datetime <', $today);
        $this->db->where('status_id', 0);
        $this->db->update('visits', 'status_id = -4 ');
    }
```

The commented query prints two records with the given conditions. So The query is supposed to update two records with the new value in the field `status_id` but it actually does not.

What am  I missing in this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the values as an array or an object to the function `update`. Try with,

```
// define array of values
$data = array(
               'status_id' => -4
            );
$this->db->where('exp_datetime <', $today);
$this->db->where('status_id', 0);
$this->db->update('visits',$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$data = array(
          'status_id' => -4
         );
$this->db->where(" exp_datetime < '".$today."'");
$this->db->where('status_id', 0);
$this->db->update('visits',$data);
```